# Is there a way in R to calculate how many times it happens that if there is a 0, the subsequent number will be also a zero?

Tags: r

I have a binary dataset with 0 and 1. Is there a way to calculate how many times it happens that if there is a 0, the subsequent number will be also a zero (so 10101**00**). And how many times it happens that there are three subsequent zeros, etc.

A zero in my data means that a bird is not on its nest at a particular time. For every three minutes, it is noted if the bird is on its nest (1) or not (0). My goal is to find out if birds in particular areas leave their nests longer because it takes them longer to get enough food. Longer means more subsequent zeros.

Comment: The `rle` function should give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
bla <- rle(c(0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0))

table(bla$lengths[bla$values == 0])
```

gives you

```
1 2 3 
1 2 1
```

meaning that a sequence of 1 zero appears once, 2 zeros twice and 3 zeros again once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use run length encoding to reconstruct this data. Suppose your data looked like this:

```r
set.seed(69)
df <- data.frame(time = seq(1:20), on_off = rbinom(20, 1, 0.5))
df
#>    time on_off
#> 1     1      1
#> 2     2      1
#> 3     3      1
#> 4     4      1
#> 5     5      0
#> 6     6      1
#> 7     7      0
#> 8     8      1
#> 9     9      0
#> 10   10      0
#> 11   11      1
#> 12   12      0
#> 13   13      1
#> 14   14      0
#> 15   15      0
#> 16   16      0
#> 17   17      0
#> 18   18      1
#> 19   19      0
#> 20   20      1
```

Then you can convert it into a run-length encoded data frame like this:

```
RLE <- rle(df$on_off)
len <- RLE$lengths
new_df <- data.frame(time = df$time[cumsum(c(1, len))[seq_along(len)]],
                     on_off = RLE$value, duration = len)

new_df
#>    time on_off duration
#> 1     1      1        4
#> 2     5      0        1
#> 3     6      1        1
#> 4     7      0        1
#> 5     8      1        1
#> 6     9      0        2
#> 7    11      1        1
#> 8    12      0        1
#> 9    13      1        1
#> 10   14      0        4
#> 11   18      1        1
#> 12   19      0        1
#> 13   20      1        1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>